# Android, Kotlin, ContentResolver: Image viewers do not recognize content uri my app has sent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

1. I want to make my app:
   1.1. Convert "file:///storage/emulated/0/a/picture.jpg" to content:// URI
   1.2. Create Intent and send to image viewer with content:// URI
   1.3. So image viewer should open and show /storage/emulated/0/a/picture.jpg
2. So I wrote some code:

```
fun AShortStory() {
    var Amy = getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
        arrayOf(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE),
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "='" + "/storage/emulated/0/a/picture.jpg" + "'",
        null,
        null
    )
    if (Amy == null) return
    if (Amy.getCount() < 1) return

    var Linda = Intent()
    Linda.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    Linda.data = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external", Amy.getString(0).toLong())
    Linda.type = Amy.getString(1)
    try {startActivity(Linda)} catch(Betty: Exception) {}
}
```

3. App launches image viewer, but any image viewer shows nothing as like it has received null

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

OK, Self-answer here.

Before:

```
Linda.data = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external", Amy.getString(0).toLong())
Linda.type = Amy.getString(1)
```

After:

```
Linda.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external", Amy.getString(0).toLong()), Amy.getString(1))
```

And image view shows the picture I requested.
It seems Intent has no support for `Intent.data = uri` and `Intent.type = mime`.